# Loop through entire workbook and delete rows that have #N/A

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a workbook with 11 sheets. I need to delete the rows in all sheets where #N/A appears. How would I go about doing this?

I have written out some code, see below, that allows me to delete only the #N/A rows that appear when my excel file is open to that specific tab. It will not loop through the entire workbook.

```
Sub RemoveErrorsLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 2 To WS_Count
         Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
     Next I

End Sub
```

I want code that will loop through all of my sheets and remove the rows that have #N/A. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just forgot to use your "I" in your loop:
if you simply add `Sheets(I).` your line will work in every sheet of the workbook.

```
Sub RemoveErrorsLoop()
         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count
             Sheets(I).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
         Next I

End Sub
```

I would even add an error handler to let the code work when you don't have #N/A in the sheet.

```
         For I = 1 To WS_Count
            On Error Resume Next
               Sheets(I).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
         Next I
```

Comment: Did not work. Gives me a runtime error '1004' and will not run through the entire workbook.

Comment: @hkml it is expected if there are no cells with category as `xlErrors`.

Comment: @hkml See the Error handler part at the end

Comment: @pierre44 you can use `If Not Sheets(I).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) is nothing then Sheets(I).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete` instead of `On Error` part.